# R: how to attach the date into timeseries(ts) object?

Tags: r, time-series

I have a `dataframe` with only 2 columns:

```
 $dt: Date, format: "2019-01-01" "2019-01-02" "2019-01-03" "2019-01-04"
 $new_user_growth: num  NA -0.0254 -0.0469 -0.1257 0.3125
```

I converted the `dataframe` to `ts` by:

```
ts_h7_2019 <- ts(data=df$new_user_growth, frequency = 7)
head(ts_h7_2019)
```

And the `head` function above returned:

```
Time Series:
Start = c(1, 1) 
End = c(1, 6) 
Frequency = 7 
[1] NA -0.02538071 -0.04687500 -0.12568306  0.31250000 -0.17142857
```

Notice that the `start` and `end` of the timeseries is integer(`c(1,1)`) instead of date(`df$dt`). How to attach the date into the `ts` object?

Comment: ts series have numeric times only with special features for handling monthly and quarterly series. You can use zoo or xts to represent a 
series with dates.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I tried `xts` but somehow it breaks the seasonality. Looks like the `frequency` parameter is not working on the `xts`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60673823/r-ts-object-shows-weekly-seasonality-but-not-xts-with-same-data-and-frequency

Comment: The question was how to add dates to a time series. If the question is how to create a regularly spaced series from irregularly spaced dates that is a different question.

Comment: sorry what do you mean by `how to create a regularly spaced series from irregularly spaced dates that is a different question`?

Comment: You discussed frequency which relates to regularly spaced series and has nothing to do with attaching dates.

Comment: A regular spaced series has, for example, a point for every day but an irregularly spaced series is one in which some days are skipped such as weekends.  It seems you have an irregularly spaced series and want to turn it into a regularly spaced one. In that case you can't use the dates since they are not regularly spaced.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the `start` parameter, which is the start date of the series.

```r
ts_h7_2019 <- ts(data=df$new_user_growth, frequency = 7, start = df[1,1])
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried your code, but it returned another value of integer instead: ```Start = c(17897, 1) 
End = c(17897, 6) ```

Comment: Yes, start has to be an integer. Try using ````start = "2019-01-01"```` and it will throw an error stating that start is non-numeric. The 17897 means 17897 days since 1st January 1970, which is 1st January 2019. If you want the character form of date in a time series object, you should consider using ```xts```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I tried `xts` but somehow it breaks the seasonality. Looks like the `frequency` parameter is not working on the `xts`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60673823/r-ts-object-shows-weekly-seasonality-but-not-xts-with-same-data-and-frequency