# R: ts object shows weekly seasonality, but not xts (with same data and frequency parameter)

Tags: r, time-series

I have a `dataframe` which captures `daily` data:

```
$dt: Date, format: "2019-01-01" "2019-01-02" "2019-01-03" "2019-01-04"
$new_user_growth: num  NA -0.0254 -0.0469 -0.1257 0.3125
```

I converted the `dataframe` above to `ts` by:

```
ts_h7_2019 <- ts(data=df$new_user_growth, frequency = 7)
```

I set `frequency` to 7 because I want to focus on weekly seasonality. When I decompose the data using `mstl` (automatic `stl` algorithm), it **shows** `Seasonal7` trend.

So far so good.

But then, I found working with `xts` is easier, so I created an `xts` object:

```
df_xts <- xts(x=df$new_user_growth, order.by=df$dt, frequency=7)
```

or alternatively, I also tried:

```
df_xts2 <- xts(x=df$new_user_growth, order.by=df$dt, deltat=7)
```

Notice that both `ts` object (`ts_h7_2019`) and `xts` object (`df_xts, df_xts2`) are derived from a **same** `dataframe` (`df`). However, the `mstl` decomposition return **no seasonality** and consequently, the manual `stl` can't be run on the `xts` objects with this error:

```
y is not a seasonal ts object
```

What's wrong here? both `xts` and `ts` should have exactly same seasonality as both are derived from a single `dataframe`.

Why does the `frequency` parameter works on `ts` but not on `xts`?

Comment: why a close request? essentially, the question is why does the `frequency` parameter works on `ts` but not on `xts`?

Comment: I think that message simply means that the object has to be a ````ts```` object, an ````xts```` object is different to a ````ts```` object.

Comment: Blaze has a point that the xts object 'looses'  the seasonality with mstl, but as mentioned in my answer one can use the `msts` class to cope with that issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the `msts`class (taken from: https://otexts.com/fpp2/complexseasonality.html).
Potentially something like this:

```
forecast::mstl(msts(data = xts(df$....), seasonal.periods = 7))
```